# Why does gcov not create coverage for all headers?

Tags: gcov

Gcov didnt provide coverage for all the header files except the ones with the following definition:
    1. If it is an interface and if the interface is implemented, then Interface.h file is shown in coverage.
    2. If a header had a inline function and if it the function was used elsewhere then the header is shown in the coverage.
    3. Or if the class is of type Q_Object with Q_OBJECT macro declared in the declaration.

So I am wondering if there is a documentation which says, what will be included in the coverage and what will not be included. Any help on this would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude Q_OBJECT macro from result try to pass `--rc lcov_excl_line=Q_OBJECT`to lcov.
There some help about exclude macro: [How to tell lcov to ignore lines in the source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264049/how-to-tell-lcov-to-ignore-lines-in-the-source-files/23264375)