# Exclude Code from Coverage in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, xcode7

How can I exclude code from coverage report in Xcode 7?

I want do to that using Swift. It will be nice to know how to do it for objective-c as well.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706968/excluding-code-from-coverage-stats-in-xcode-7 , but that question isn't answered either.