# Exclude Files/Lines of code in Xcode 7 Code Coverage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, code-coverage, xcode7

How would you exclude a few methods, or say the AppDelegate file, from being tested during Code Coverage in Xcode 7?

I am not using Gcov.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32706968/335858

Answer (score 15):

Xcode coverage is generated by target (you can enabled it per scheme).  Something I often do is separate all my testable code into a separate DynamicFramework from all my UI code. I can generate coverage just for that one framework if i like.
[image]

Alternatively you could look at some of the 3rd party coverage parsing tools such as:

- [xcov](https://github.com/nakiostudio/xcov)
- [slather](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather)

Each tool will generate you a set of coverage metrics (based on the coverage data generated by Xcode) and they have the ability to exclude specific files from the coverage generation.

#### Xcov

```
--ignore_file_path -x: Relative or absolute path to the file containing the list of ignored files.
```

#### Slather

```
# .slather.yml
ignore:
 - ExamplePodCode/*
 - ProjectTestsGroup/*
```

*Personally I find that xcov is nicer to look at but slather is slightly more detailed*

Comment: Unfortunately, xcov doesn't respect the ignore files when calculating total coverage:

https://github.com/nakiostudio/xcov/issues/130

Comment: I have some Guard statements in the code, for safe programming, which should never be invoked. Code coverage says my code never reaches these locations, thus is not 100%. Is there anyway to correct this using some inline macro?