# Exclude files from Xcode code coverage report

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage

Is there any way to exclude files in XCode code coverage.

I did research and found some tools here - [Exclude Files/Lines of code in Xcode 7 Code Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887690/exclude-files-lines-of-code-in-xcode-7-code-coverage)

But all these are third party tools. Is there any way we can do it in xcode it self??

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 10.0, you can only exclude complete targets, not individual files.

Here's how to do it: `Edit Scheme -> Test -> Options`:

[image: Code coverage target selection]