# Xcode code coverage: How to exclude framework code?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, swift3, code-coverage

I have a unit test that tests my target application.  My target application depends on a dynamic framework.

When the code coverage results come back, it lists my target application's code coverage as well as the dynamic framework's

I do not want to get the dynamic framework to give code coverage.  Is it possible to exclude it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887690/exclude-files-lines-of-code-in-xcode-7-code-coverage

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters when using [llvm cov]：
-ignore-filename-regex="File path you want to exclude"