# Exclude views from code coverage in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

How do you exclude views (table cells, custom buttons, etc) from code coverage statistics for an iOS project in Xcode? They don't have any useful functionality, only IBOutlets and some animations, and I don't want them to be included in the results.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706968/excluding-code-from-coverage-stats-in-xcode-7, which has no answer.